# tsql как сгруппировать и вывести результат в нужно шаблоне?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица:

[image: Таблица1]

Нужно, соединить  по полю group и получить результат в следующием виде.
В зависимости от значение Field, отображать значение либо в Field1, либо Field2.
Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(ID) as ID,
       group,
       max(case when Field='F1' then Value end) as Field1,
       max(case when Field='F2' then Value end) as Field2
  from Table
 group by Group
```

Либо воспользоваться [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select grp, F1 as Filed1, F2 as Field2
  from (
   select grp, val, field
     from Tab
  ) p
  pivot (
    max(val) for field in(F1,F2)
  ) pvt
```