# Вывод одних и тех же элементов несколько раз в одном запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос к mysql:

```
  SELECT
ProductName, ProductImages, ProductDescription,
ProductPrice, ProductAddDate, cSchema_Name, cValueValue
  FROM 
Product p INNER JOIN CharacteristicsValue cv
ON p.ID_product = cv.cValueProduct_FK
INNER JOIN CharacteristicsSchema cs 
ON cv.cValueSchema_FK = cs.ID_cSchema
  WHERE 
ProductUrl = ? 
AND cv.cValueSchema_FK = cs.ID_cSchema 
AND cs.cSchema_Category_FK = p.ProductCategory_FK");
```

Структура этих таблиц в БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результатом этого запроса есть следующее:

> ProductName = HP ProBook 4540s
>   
>  ProductImages = 
>   
>  ProductDescription = Классный ноутбук
>   
>  ProductPrice = 99999 грн
>   
>  ProductAddDate = 2016-12-21
>   
>  cSchema_Name = Частота процессора
>   
>  cValueValue = 1.7 GHZ
>   
>  ProductName = HP ProBook 4540s
>   
>  ProductImages = 
>   
>  ProductDescription = Классный ноутбук
>   
>  ProductPrice = 99999 грн
>   
>  ProductAddDate = 2016-12-21
>   
>  cSchema_Name = Оперативная память
>   
>  cValueValue = 4 GB
>   
>  ProductName = HP ProBook 4540s
>   
>  ProductImages = 
>   
>  ProductDescription = Классный ноутбук
>   
>  ProductPrice = 99999 грн
>   
>  ProductAddDate = 2016-12-21
>   
>  cSchema_Name = Диагональ экрана
>   
>  cValueValue = 15.6'
>   
>  ProductName = HP ProBook 4540s
>   
>  ProductImages = 
>   
>  ProductDescription = Классный ноутбук
>   
>  ProductPrice = 99999 грн
>   
>  ProductAddDate = 2016-12-21
>   
>  cSchema_Name = Количество USB-портов
>   
>  cValueValue = 2
>   
>  ProductName = HP ProBook 4540s
>   
>  ProductImages = 
>   
>  ProductDescription = Классный ноутбук
>   
>  ProductPrice = 99999 грн
>   
>  ProductAddDate = 2016-12-21
>   
>  cSchema_Name = Разрешение экрана
>   
>  cValueValue = 1366x768

Как видно из этого, значения из таблицы *Product* выводятся несколько раз, что излишне. 

Подскажите, или направьте на путь, как этого избежать?

Ожидаемый результат должен быть таким:

> ProductName = HP ProBook 4540s
>   
>  ProductImages = 
>   
>  ProductDescription = Классный ноутбук
>   
>  ProductPrice = 99999 грн
>   
>  ProductAddDate = 2016-12-21
>   
>  cSchema_Name = Частота процессора
>   
>  cValueValue = 1.7 GHZ
>   
>  cSchema_Name = Оперативная память
>   
>  cValueValue = 4 GB
>   
>  cSchema_Name = Диагональ экрана
>   
>  cValueValue = 15.6'

Comment: ну так правильно, к ноуту же прикреплены разные компоненты, проц/оператива/тд, они все и выводятся.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, оно то так, но, мне нужно, чтобы значения из таблицы Product выводились 1 раз. Понятно, что то, что у меня - это декартово произведение, а как сделать объединение - пока проблема.

Comment: Для начала надо решить что в результате запроса должно произойти с этими самыми колонками, которые не повторяются. Т.е. с тем что из Characteristics. сразу обращаю внимание, что выбрать заранее не фиксированные в запросе колонки (что бы их кол-во динамически менялось) невозможно. Приведите в вопросе как должен выглядеть результат правильного запроса

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за совет, добавил.

Comment: Ну вот так как вы хотите - как раз не возможно. так можно развернуть только на клиенте. Или выбрать строго 3 параметра (определенных заранее), например так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590351/ (для MySQL подходит только первый вариант)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень жаль, что нельзя получить ожидаемый результат одним запросом, как подсказывает @Mike. 
Что ж, пришлось сделать двумя запросами:

1):

```
"SELECT ProductName, ProductImages, ProductDescription,
        ProductPrice, ProductAddDate, ID_product, ProductCategory_FK
 FROM Product
 WHERE ProductUrl = ?"
```

2):

```
"SELECT cSchema_Name, cValueValue 
 FROM CharacteristicsValue cv
 JOIN CharacteristicsSchema cs ON cv.ID_cValue = cs.ID_cSchema 
 WHERE cv.cValueProduct_FK = ? AND cs.cSchema_Category_FK = ?"
```

Полный php-код:

```
$stmt = $tmp_conn->prepare("SELECT ProductName, ProductImages, ProductDescription,
            ProductPrice, ProductAddDate, ID_product, ProductCategory_FK
            FROM Product
            WHERE ProductUrl = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $url);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    $result->free_result();

    $id_prod = $data[0]['ID_product'];
    $id_category = $data[0]['ProductCategory_FK'];

    $stmt = $tmp_conn->prepare("SELECT cSchema_Name, cValueValue 
            FROM CharacteristicsValue cv
            INNER JOIN CharacteristicsSchema cs ON cv.ID_cValue = cs.ID_cSchema 
            WHERE cv.cValueProduct_FK = ? AND cs.cSchema_Category_FK = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $id_prod, $id_category);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    $result->free_result();
```

И что получилось в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]